# Pi2 with Kodi, output to composite video only works in some cases

Tags: kodi, composite-video

Having set up one Kodi installation via HDMI on my TV, I now want another for my projector, using composite video. The Pi OS (Raspbian) is delivering composite just fine, and so does the Kodi home page, menus etc. But when I actually try to watch a video stream, some streams (eg YouTube) work just fine, while others (eg BBC iPlayer) do not. The stream is playing, as I can hear the audio, but all I see is the Kodi screen from which I launched it.

Update: I have tried a few more addons, and the problem seems to be related to the specific addon. This is what I've tried so far:

BBC iPlayer by Mikey1234 version 0.2.0
Live: audio only
Catchup: audio and video

iPlayer WWW by CaptainT,Cas,ihurst,primaeval version 1.3.1
Live: Audio only
Catchup: audio only

ITVPlayer by Mikey1234 version 2.2.6
Live: audio only
Catchup: audio and video

Nasa by Tristan Fischer version 2.0.3
Live: audio only
Catchup: audio and video

So it seems to be specific to something the individual addon is (not) doing, but it is also specific to using composite video, as everything is fine on HDMI.

Update 2: I have also now added the Gert VGA666 adapter, and can use that successfully in all cases that did not work on composite. This solves my immediate problem (as my projector has composite and VGA, but not HDMI), but still leaves me wondering why composite does not universally work.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try `hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1` in the config.txt and reboot, see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md (but this is only guesswork on my part, the more I think about it the less likely it seems)

Comment: @Ghanima - Thanks for the suggestion, but I already had that setting.

Comment: I think the problem probably arises from the application itself, opposed  to being  a problem with Kodi. Some of these applications might have been designed to work with newer models of the Pi which do not have a RCA port on them. Or the applications originally supported RCA, but through updates support for RCA was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Composite Video is limited to Standard Definition (SD) Video, while the BBC iPlayer and ITVPlayer live streams are generally HD.

Have you tried setting a lower screen resolution (480p for example) as described here?

http://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/System